# use old dsl modem as router

Tags: networking, internet-connection, dsl-modem

I have only one ethernet port available on my NanoStation loco M5:
[image: http://davidddp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ns2-modocliente1.jpg]

But I need to connect 2 PCs to the internet now. Do I have to get new router or is it possible (how?) to use my old dsl modem (4 LAN ports, model [XAVi X7822r](http://www.t-mobile.cz/dcpublic/X7822r-manual.pdf)?

Comment: Really, you need a network switch and not another router!
It will cost you less in electricity etc.

Comment: If the old dsl modem has a WAN port this is possible.  If it does not then you require new hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need another router. You'll want to use a switch for this. The four LAN ports on your X7822r can be used as one. First, you need to make sure the router you're about to install will not interfere with the rest of the network by disabling this router's DHCP server. Then, hook the LAN ports up to your PCs and existing infrastructure, do not use the WAN port. The device will behave, for the most part, as a 'dumb' switch.

Comment: There is no reason he cannot leave DHCP enable on the gateway he wishes to use.  This of course assumes the device has a WAN port on it.